# Custom log based on Marker

Tags: java, slf4j

Anyone knows if it is possible to create log files based on custom Markers using slf4j?

My Log with my custom Marker:

```
Marker myCustomMarker = MarkerFactory.getMarker("MY_CUSTOM_MARKER");
logger.error(myCustomMarker , "My application log.");
```

My logback.xml with **logs/%marker.log**

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>logs/%marker.log</file>
        <append>false</append>
        <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.mkyong" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

but the result was /logs.log%marker

Thanks for any help